# FileInputStream leaving weird garbage text after skip() call

Tags: java, android, inputstream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

The need:

I want to write data into compressed and normal format as well. When I'll have to write data into compressed format "useCompression" will be sent as "true" and "useCompression" will be false when data needs to be stored in normal(as it is given to the Writer class) format.

The problem here is, how will I identify whether the data is compressed or not later when Reader class is trying to read the data?
So, to solve the problem, I am writing "1" into file if is "useCompression" is true and "0" if "useCompression" is false.

writing is fine, but when we try to skip the first element using "fIn.skip(1)" cause it is the identifier and not actual data, it is leaving behind some garbage value.

For, example, I am trying to write "2019-07-31" into a file and "useCompression" is false, so my file will hold "02019-07-31" and post "fIn.skip(1)" call it should hold "2019-07-31" but it is holding "^@2019-07-31".

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here

I've tried to update Reader class's constructor as:

```
    public Reader(String key)
    {
        mKey = key;
        try {
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(streamFileForKey(key));
            byte[] firstByte = new byte[1];
            int read = fIn.read(firstByte);
            boolean shouldUseDecompression = (1 == firstByte[0]);

            if (shouldUseDecompression) {
                mFin = new GZIPInputStream(fIn);
            }
            else {
                mFin = fIn;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to open (r) key " + key + " exception : " + e);
        }
    }
```

But it does not solve the problem.

The actual code is:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class forStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        // Write to normal file
        mReader1 = new Reader(mInputFileName);
        mWriter1 = new Writer(mOutputFilename1, false);
        int availableBytes = mReader1.availableBytes();
        int readBytes = 1000;
        while (availableBytes > 0)
        {
            if (availableBytes >= 1000) {
                availableBytes = availableBytes - readBytes;
            }
            else {
                readBytes = availableBytes;
                availableBytes = availableBytes - readBytes;
            }

            mWriter1.write(mReader1.read(readBytes), 0, readBytes);
        }
        mReader1.close();
        mWriter1.close();
    }

    private static File streamFileForKey(String key)
    {
        return new File(key);
    }

    static String mInputFileName = "~/Downloads/inputStream.txt";
    static String mOutputFilename1 = "~/Downloads/outputStream.txt";

    static Reader mReader1;

    static Writer mWriter1;

    private static class Writer
    {
        public Writer(String key, boolean useCompression) {
            mKey = key;

            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(streamFileForKey(key));
                if (useCompression) {
                    fileOutput.write(1);
                    gOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fileOutput);
                }
                else {
                    fileOutput.write(0);
                    gOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(fileOutput);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Got error while opening stream for " + mKey + ". Ex: " + e);
            }
        }

        public boolean write(byte[] bytes, int pos, int len)
        {
            boolean retVal = true;

            if (gOutputStream == null) {
                return false;
            }

            try {
                gOutputStream.write(bytes, pos, len);
                retVal = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to write " + len + " bytes to key " +
                        mKey + e);
                retVal = false;
            }

            return retVal;
        }

        public void close()
        {
            if (gOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    gOutputStream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to close key " + mKey + e);
                }
                gOutputStream = null;
            }
        }

        private String mKey;
        private OutputStream gOutputStream;
    }

    private static class Reader
    {
        public Reader(String key)
        {
            mKey = key;
            try {
                FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(streamFileForKey(key));

                if (shouldUseDecompression()) {
                    long skipped = fIn.skip(1);
                    mFin = new GZIPInputStream(fIn);
                }
                else {
                    long skipped = fIn.skip(1);
                    mFin = fIn;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to open (r) key " + key + " exception : " + e);
            }
        }

        public byte[] read(int len)
        {
            if (mFin == null) {
                return null;
            }

            byte[] b = null;
            try {
                b = new byte[len];
                int read;
                read = mFin.read(b, 0, len);
                if (read <= 0) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to read " + len + " bytes from key " +
                        mKey + " exception : " + e);
            }

            return b;
        }

        public void close()
        {
            if (mFin != null) {
                try {
                    mFin.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to close key " + mKey + " exception : " + e);
                }
                mFin = null;
            }
        }

        private boolean shouldUseDecompression()
        {
            boolean retVal = false;
            try {
                FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(streamFileForKey(mKey));
                byte[] firstByte = new byte[1];
                int read = fIn.read(firstByte);

                // If first byte is `1` the we need to use decompression on it.
                retVal = (1 == firstByte[0]);
                fIn.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in shouldUseDecompression() : " + e);
                retVal = false;
            }

            return retVal;
        }

        public int availableBytes()
        {
            int available = 0;
            try {
                if (mFin != null) {
                    available = mFin.available();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to read available bytes for " + mKey + ". Exception : " + e);
            }

            return available;
        }

        private String mKey;
        private InputStream mFin;
    }
}
```

The expected result should be, post "fIn.skip(1)" call file should hold "2019-07-31" and not "^@2019-07-31".

Comment: Why are you using `DataOutputStream`? Just set `gOutputStream = fileOutput` when not compressing.

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice when reading? Just open the file and use `read()` to read the first byte. You then have the value to determine is compression was used, *and* the stream is positioned to read the data.

Comment: @Andreas,   
For first question, Even after doing `gOutputStream = fileOutput` it does not help. I had done it so that I can know how much data is gone inside stream(but that I've not implemented yet).   
For Second Question, I've tried it, that also does not help. I've updated my question. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle, I found out that it was the expected result.
*^@* was nothing but the binary *0* I was writing from Writer class's constructor incase *useCompression* was false.
From line `fileOutput.write(0);`.